# Maya Python multiple functions to one button

Tags: python, button, maya, function

I am creating a rig through scripting and I have a UI. I would like to connect multiple functions to one button. Or rather, have a function inside of a function. Any suggestions on how to go about this issue?

I am importing the following libraries:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial
```

Comment: What is your GUI library of choice?  It's also unclear what you mean by "multiple functions."  Do you means you press a button and it calls two functions?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain further more what you to do with a little example ?

I see you want to use partial so you may have multiple variables to pass through  ?

My first idea would to create a function grouping your multiples function, ie :

```
def temp01():
    return cmds.ls(sl=True)

def connection(obj01, obj02):
    someCommand(obj01, obj02)

def printor():
    print('yeah it is working')


def uiCommandButton_whatShouldIDoFunc(obj02, specialOkay, *args): 
    someCommand(temp01(), obj02)
    specialOkay() #should print message

button01 = cmds.button(c=partial( uiCommandButton_whatShouldIDoFunc, cmds.ls(sl=1)[-1]), printor )
```

Answer (score 0):

To have things nice and clean, I would use *handlers*.

A handler is a method that is called when an event occurs on your GUI element, like click. In the handler you can do whatever you want to (like calling your two functions). Handlers/event handlers are a tried and test GUI programming technique.

Here is an example:

```
my_button = cmds.button(command=partial(my_button_on_click_handler, arg1, arg2))

def my_button_on_click_handler(arg1, arg2):
    # call all your functions and do stuff here
    my_other_func1(arg1)
    my_other_func2(arg2)
```

Some great posts on this topic (courtesy: @theodox and his awesome blog):
http://techartsurvival.blogspot.ca/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html?m=1

http://techartsurvival.blogspot.ca/2014/04/the-main-event-event-oriented.html?m=1

Comment: some links for [maya callbacks in general](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)  and [events in particular](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/the-main-event-event-oriented.html)

Comment: Great links as usual. Thanks @theodox!

Answer (score 0):

There is a "dirty" way of doing so by using PyMel and PySide/Qt.

First, turn your button into Pymel button :

```
import pymel.core as pm
import pymel.core.uitypes as pui

pyBtn = pm.button(label="", etc...)
or
pyBtn = pui.PyUI(my_button)
```

Then, convert it to a QtObject:

```
qtBtn = pyBtn.asQtObject()
```

And finally, you can add functions when the button is clicked like that:

```
qtBtn.clicked.connect(func1)
qtBtn.clicked.connect(partial(func2, arg1))
etc...
```

But like I said, this is not really recommended... It's just another way of doing it.
I thought it might be interesting to share it.
As an example, you can use this solution if the UI already exists, but you can't access the code that creates it.

Otherwise, I would do like suggested in the other answers, creating handlers functions.

PS : This will only works with maya2014 and above, or a maya with PyQt installed !